# How to create a dynamic dropdown in Flask?

Tags: python, html, flask

**All the questions I referred to on SO were displaying results of creating a dynamic dropdown where they made use of database, I am not making use of a database but making use of a CSV file to fetch data, so those answers couldn't help me**

here is my app.py file

```
@app.route('/StatsPage', methods=['GET','POST'])
def StatsPage():
    timeline=['Daily', 'Weekly', 'Monthly']
    return render_template('StatsPage.html', timeline=timeline)

@app.route('/StatsPage/timing', methods=['GET','POST'])
def get_timeline(timing):
    dates_dict=['2020-08-23', '2020-08-24', '2020-08-25', '2020-08-26', '2020-08-27', '2020-08-28', '2020-08-29', '2020-08-30', '2020-08-31', '2020-09-01', '2020-09-02', '2020-09-03', '2020-09-04', '2020-09-05', '2020-09-06', '2020-09-07', '2020-09-08', '2020-09-09']
    months=['August', 'September']
    week=['2020-08-23', '2020-08-30', '2020-09-06', '2020-09-13', '2020-09-20']
   
    timelines={
    'Daily': dates_dict,
    'Weekly': week,
    'Monthly': months
    }

    return jsonify(timelines[timing])
```

Here is my `StatsPage.html` file

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}


  <article class="media content-section">
    <div class="media-body">
      <div class="article-metadata">
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <form method="POST" action="/StatsPage"> 
          <select class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" style="background-color: #FFFFFF; color:  #105583;" name="selectedTimeline">
            <option style="color:  #105583;" disabled selected value= "">Select the option</option>
              {% for t in timeline  %}
                <option style="color:  #105583;" value= "{{t}}" SELECTED>{{t}}</option>"
              {% endfor %}
          </select>
          <select class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" style="background-color: #FFFFFF; color:  #105583;" name="selectedDate">
              {% for d in dates_dict %}
                <option style="color:  #105583;" value= "{{d}}" SELECTED>{{d}}</option>"
              {% endfor %}
          </select>
          <button type="submit" name="" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Generate Results</button>
        </form>  
      </div>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
      crossorigin="anonymous">
      </script>
      <script>
            $('select[name=selectedTimeline]').change(function() {
              timing = this.value
              $.get('/DailyStats/'+timing, function(data, status){
                $('select[name=selectedDate]').html('')
                data.forEach(function(date){
                  $('select[name=selectedDate]').append('<option>'+date+'</option>')
                })
              })
            })
      </script>
    </div>
  </article>
  

{% endblock content %}
```

All I want to do is
When the user selects the option Daily, the elements in the `days_dict` list should be displayed, when the user selects the option Weekly, the elements in the `week` list should be displayed and when the user selects the option Monthly the elements in the `months` list should be displayed.

I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44646925/flask-dynamic-dependent-dropdown-list/44654011) question on SO, for retrieving the option selected from the first dropdown using AJAX but it didn't help me
So please can someone help me to get this working

Result after answer1
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change the syntax in your flask URL. Also you can use AJAX

```
@app.route('/StatsPage/<timing>', methods=['GET','POST'])
def get_timeline(timing):
```

Include Jquery CDN.

```
<article class="media content-section">
  <div class="media-body">
    <div class="article-metadata">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <form method="POST" action="/StatsPage"> 
        <select class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" style="background-color: #FFFFFF; color:  #105583;" name="selectedTimeline">
              <option style="color:  #105583;" disabled selected value= "">Select the option</option>
            {% for t in timeline  %}
              <option style="color:  #105583;" value= "{{t}}">{{t}}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
        <select class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" style="background-color: #FFFFFF; color:  #105583;" name="selectedDate">
            {% for d in dates_dict %}
              <option style="color:  #105583;" value= "{{d}}">{{d}}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
        <button type="submit" name="" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Generate Results</button>
      </form>  
    </div>
  </div>
</article>

<script>
  $('select[name=selectedTimeline]').change(function() {
    timing = this.value
    $.get('/DailyStats/'+timing, function(data, status){
      $('select[name=selectedDate]').html('')
      data.forEach(function(date){
        $('select[name=selectedDate]').append('<option>'+date+'</option>')
      })
    })
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, it doesn't work for me...I have edited the question to display the output after I tried following the steps and pasting your solution

Comment: the same code working for me. can u just send the request to /DailyStats/timing in browser and check the output?

Comment: I get this ```TypeError: get_timeline() missing 1 required positional argument: 'timing'```

Comment: add bracket like this
@app.route('/DailyStats/<timing>', methods=['GET','POST'])

Comment: The ```/DailyStats/timing``` route displays the corresponding values, but I can't get the values on my dropdown

Comment: I have edited the question as per the current status of my files...can't really understand where the issue lies, please can you help by referring to the edited part again

Comment: Is it because of the jinja template that I use?

Comment: Jinja is not a problem. For me it is working. have you tested like, /DailyStats/Daily or /DailyStats/Weekly in your browser? Are you getting the data correctly?

Comment: Yes, I do get a json displayed of the lists

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224432/discussion-between-navaneetha-krishnan-and-glen-veigas).